# nginx matches wrong server block

Tags: nginx, https

I'm setting up an nginx configuration.

- HTTPS/HTTP2 in enabled.
- All traffic should be redirected to HTTPS.
- All www requests should be redirected to non-www (naked domain).

My current setup looks more or less like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen       443 http2 ssl;
    server_name  localhost  domain.com;
    (...)
}
```

I'v tested the following scenario's:

- http://domain.com - 301 Moved Permanently (OK)
- http://www.domain.com - 301 Moved Permanently (OK)
- https://domain.com - 200 (OK)
- https://www.domain.com - 200 (FAILED: expected 301 Moved Permanently)

The last one is incorrect. Can anyone explain why and how this can be fixed?

Comment: Do you have ssl related settings in the `www.domain.com` server block?

Comment: That's it, i forgot to add the other ssl config (like the actual cert) to the block. Sigh, late night coding...